# Is it possible run DBCC CHECKDB on a single partition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to run DBCC CHECKDB on a single partition in sql server? I know we could use CHECKFILEGROUP if the partitions are on separate filegroups but what if the partitions are not on separate filegroups? Is there an option to specify the partition no with CHECKDB?

Answer (score 6):

Nope - I never got around to writing a partition-only consistency check when I rewrote CHECKDB. CHECKFILEGROUP is your only option.

Thanks

Comment: is it possible to add it to your requested feature list?

Comment: Plus one for being the actual guy who wrote CheckDB :)